# Maven spring boot multi module project in intellij not building successfully after maven package command

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot, intellij-idea

I have a spring boot multi-module project in IntelliJ, The problem is, when I run the project in IntelliJ, it builds and works as expected but when I try a maven package, I get this error:

> The POM for `ng.biosec:enrollment_ws:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT` is missing, no
>   dependency information available and The POM for
>   `ng.biosec:abis_module:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT` is missing, no dependency
>   information available

and then the process fails.

Here is my pom.xml for the the two modules and the parent:
`enrollment_ws.xml` pom

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

<parent>
        <artifactId>integron</artifactId>
        <groupId>ng.biosec</groupId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <artifactId>enrollment_ws</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <dependencies>


    </dependencies>
</project>
```

This is the `abis_module.xml` pom file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <artifactId>integron</artifactId>
        <groupId>ng.biosec</groupId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <artifactId>abis_module</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>



</project>
```

This is the `cpm.xml` pom file that depends on the modules that contain the pom files mentioned above:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <artifactId>integron</artifactId>
        <groupId>ng.biosec</groupId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <artifactId>cpm</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ng.biosec</groupId>
            <artifactId>enrollment_ws</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ng.biosec</groupId>
            <artifactId>abis_module</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.ws</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-ws-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>


</project>
```

The `cpm` module contains the Spring boot application class. This is the Spring Application class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableScheduling
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"integron"})
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"integron"})
@EntityScan(basePackages = {"integron"})
public class BioConnectApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(BioConnectApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Also, this is the parent pom file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <modules>
        <module>enrollment_ws</module>
        <module>cpm</module>
        <module>verification</module>
        <module>abis_module</module>
    </modules>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.1.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from integron.repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>ng.biosec</groupId>
    <artifactId>integron</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <name>integron</name>
    <description>Bio Connect Project</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>

            <!-- tag::wsdl[] -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.13.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <schemaLanguage>WSDL</schemaLanguage>
                    <generatePackage>integron.client</generatePackage>

                    <schemas>
                        <schema>
                            <url>********?wsdl</url>
                        </schema>
                    </schemas>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <!-- end::wsdl[] -->
        </plugins>
    </build>


    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>



</project>
```

Also:
I replaced the link to the `WSDL` file for security reason, but the maven project also does not generate classes from the `WSDL`. Any help with that will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try running `mvn clean install` and check your local `.m2` repo for generated `pom` and `jar` files.

Comment: Where can i find the .m2 repo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should remove the `<parent>` element declaration from your ***integron*** module descriptor and move it to the sub-modules.

The *spring-boot-maven-plugin* should only be declared within the module holding your *Spring Boot* application i.e. the ***cpm*** module.

Here down how the *integron* project descriptor should be:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <modules>
        <module>enrollment_ws</module>
        <module>cpm</module>
        <module>verification</module>
        <module>abis_module</module>
    </modules>

    <groupId>ng.biosec</groupId>
    <artifactId>integron</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <name>integron</name>
    <description>Bio Connect Project</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <!-- tag::wsdl[] -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.13.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <schemaLanguage>WSDL</schemaLanguage>
                    <generatePackage>integron.client</generatePackage>
                    <schemas>
                        <schema>
                            <url>********?wsdl</url>
                        </schema>
                    </schemas>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <!-- end::wsdl[] -->
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

The *cpm* module descriptor should be as follows:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.1.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from integron.repository -->
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <artifactId>cpm</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ng.biosec</groupId>
            <artifactId>enrollment_ws</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ng.biosec</groupId>
            <artifactId>abis_module</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.ws</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-ws-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</project>
```

Concerning the *wsdl* generated files, I guess they are getting generated but not packaged as the parent module packaging is set to be as *pom*.

Comment: Glad to hear it :)